# Intuitive meaning for Kan fibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Other than the formal definition of Kan fibration (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kan_fibration), is there any intuitive meaning of Kan fibration?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a morphism that has a combinatorial version of the homotopy lifting property.